# Getting Block Hash of another contract

Tags: solidity, block

I've seen some problems with calling functions from other contracts but I believe my problem is fairly genuine to demand a separate question if only to be negated in its possibility.
So I am trying to call a contract within another contract. Is it possible to get the blockhash of a particular block number of the callee contract within my caller? If so how?

Every syntax I've attempted fails for some reason.

Contract A

`enter code here`

```
contract DiceGame {

uint256 public nonce = 0;
uint256 public prize = 0;

event Roll(address indexed player, uint256 roll);
event Winner(address winner, uint256 amount);

constructor() payable {
    resetPrize();
}

function resetPrize() private {
    prize = ((address(this).balance * 10) / 100);
}

function rollTheDice() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.002 ether, "Failed to send enough value");

    bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, address(this), nonce));
    uint256 roll = uint256(hash) % 16;

    console.log('\t',"   Dice Game Roll:",roll);

    nonce++;
    prize += ((msg.value * 40) / 100);

    emit Roll(msg.sender, roll);

    if (roll > 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    uint256 amount = prize;
    (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

    resetPrize();
    emit Winner(msg.sender, amount);
}

receive() external payable {  }
```

}

Contract B

```
enter code here

 contract RiggedRoll is Ownable {

DiceGame public diceGame;

constructor(address payable diceGameAddress) {
    diceGame = DiceGame(diceGameAddress);
}

//Add withdraw function to transfer ether from the rigged contract to an address


//Add riggedRoll() function to predict the randomness in the DiceGame contract and only roll when it's going to be a winner

function riggedRoll(bytes32 riggedHash) public payable {
    riggedHash = address(diceGame).blockhash(block.number-1); //I am aware this syntax is broken but I am not able to find a legitimate one to access the data from contract A.
}

//Add receive() function so contract can receive Eth

receive() external payable { }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A contract doesn't know when it was last called, unless you explicitly store this information.

Then you can get the block hash using the native `blockhash()` function (accepts the block number as a parameter).

```
contract Target {
  uint256 public lastCalledAtBlockNumber;

  // The value is stored only if you invoke the function using a (read-write) transaction.
  // If you invoke the function using a (read-only) call, then it's not stored.
  function foo() external {
    lastCalledAtBlockNumber = block.number;
  }
}
```

```
bytes32 blockHash = blockhash(block.number);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Petr. This really helps and I understand the above mentioned syntax. But I have two contracts which I will put below. Now this blockhash syntax is part of a composite function in Contract A but I want this info to proceed with my problem in contract B.

Comment: @Kage Your `rollTheDice()` function needs to store the block number (or hash) in a storage property with `public` visibility (same as my `lastCalledAtBlockNumber` in the answer).  Then you'll be able to read its value from Contract B using an autogenerated getter function: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions